# iOS OpenGL ES 2.0 MultiTexturing Decal is Semi-Transparent

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I have a function that adds billboard quads to which I map a texture. This texture moves around a 3D globe as it is rotated. My drawInRect looks like this:

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    // Clear the buffer and prepare to draw
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Enable the Earth texture
    self.effect.texture2d0.name = _earthInfo.name;
    self.effect.texture2d0.target = _earthInfo.target;

    // Bind the earth vertex array
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_earthVertexArray);

    // Render the object with GLKit
    [self.effect prepareToDraw];

    // Draw elements from the index array and uv / vertex / normal info
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,Earth_polygoncount*3,GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,0);

    // Draw the SkyBox -- Draw skybox centered on eye position
//    _skyboxEffect.center = _eyePosition;
//    _skyboxEffect.transform.projectionMatrix = self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix;
//    _skyboxEffect.transform.modelviewMatrix = self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix;
//    [_skyboxEffect prepareToDraw];
//    [_skyboxEffect draw];

    // Turn on Blending before displaying satellites
    // so that the satellite image ( which has alpha )
    // shows up OK
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);

    // Now billboard something
    [self createBillboardAtLat:35 andLon:-97];

    // Now billboard something
    [self createBillboardAtLat:0 andLon:0];

    // Now billboard something
    [self createBillboardAtLat:-65 andLon:-137];

}
```

In the createBillboardAt function, I draw like so:

```
// Create a billboard that always faces the camera
- (void)createBillboardAtLat:(float)lat andLon:(float)lon {

    ... Do stuff ....

    // Assign the new matrix to draw with - no translation
    self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = noTranslationInfo;

    // Render the object with GLKit
    [self.effect prepareToDraw];

    // Draw elements from the index array and uv / vertex / normal info
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,Billboard_polygoncount*3,GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,0);

    // Restore the original matrix
    self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = originalMat;

}
```

I turn on blending before adding the billboards but at some orientations, the textures for hte satellites blend just fine with the Globe but not each other. Please see the screenshot... What am I doing wrong?

I've tried all of these options but none work - it is only one ( the foremost ) satellite that eclipses only one of the other satellites - not both. Please help!

```
    // Turn on Blending before displaying satellites
    // so that the satellite image ( which has alpha )
    // shows up OK
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    //glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    //glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    //glDepthMask(true);
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like a depth buffer issue. Perhaps the smaller satellite in the above image was drawn later, but is farther away in depth?

Comment: Your blend func seems a bit off for what you are trying to make.. Pleas try to switch it for glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); and report if the problem is fixed.

Comment: Nope changing to: glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); does not fix the problem. Do you guys have any other ideas?